# How to create custom Character using Assembly language

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, atmel, microprocessors, atmelstudio

I wrote a code in Assembly Language using Atmel studio to view a sentence on an lcd display:

```
.include "m328pdef.inc" // Include AVR atmega328p library
.org 0x00 // Start address

LDI R20,0XFF
OUT DDRD,R20
SBI DDRB,0
SBI DDRB,1

LDI R21,0x01 // clear display screen
CALL COMMAND
LDI R21,0x38 // set 8-bit 2 line 5x7 dots
CALL COMMAND
LDI R21,0x0F // display on, cursor blinking
CALL COMMAND

MAIN:
LDI R21,'L'
CALL LETTER
LDI R21,'O'
CALL LETTER
LDI R21,'A'
CALL LETTER
LDI R21,'D'
CALL LETTER
LDI R21,'I'
CALL LETTER
LDI R21,'N'
CALL LETTER
LDI R21,'G'
CALL LETTER

LDI R21,0xC0 // force cursor to start on second row
CALL COMMAND

LDI R21,'I'
CALL LOADING
LDI R21,'I'
CALL LOADING
LDI R21,'I'
CALL LOADING
LDI R21,'I'
CALL LOADING
LDI R21,'I'
CALL LOADING
LDI R21,'I'
CALL LOADING
LDI R21,'I'
CALL LOADING
LDI R21,'I'
CALL LOADING
LDI R21,'I'
CALL LOADING

LDI R21,0x01 // CLEAR DISPLAY
CALL COMMAND

LDI R21,0x80 // FORCE CURSOR TO BIGIN ON 1ST ROW
CALL COMMAND

LDI R21,'L'
CALL LETTER
LDI R21,'O'
CALL LETTER
LDI R21,'A'
CALL LETTER
LDI R21,'D'
CALL LETTER
LDI R21,'I'
CALL LETTER
LDI R21,'N'
CALL LETTER
LDI R21,'G'
CALL LETTER

LDI R21,0xC0 // force cursor to start on second row
CALL COMMAND

LDI R21,'E'
CALL LETTER
LDI R21,'N'
CALL LETTER
LDI R21,'D'
CALL LETTER
LDI R21,'E'
CALL LETTER
LDI R21,'D'
CALL LETTER

LOADING:
OUT PORTD,R21
CALL DELAY2
SBI PORTB,1 // RS = 1
CALL DELAY2
SBI PORTB,0 // E = 1
CALL DELAY2
CBI PORTB,0  // E = 0
RET

LETTER:
OUT PORTD,R21
CALL DELAY
SBI PORTB,1 // RS = 1
CALL DELAY
SBI PORTB,0 // E = 1
CALL DELAY
CBI PORTB,0  // E = 0
RET

COMMAND:
OUT PORTD,R21
CALL DELAY
CBI PORTB,1  // RS = 0
CALL DELAY
SBI PORTB,0 // E = 1
CALL DELAY
CBI PORTB,0 // E = 0
RET

DELAY:
LDI R22,10 //X = 10
LOOP1:
LDI R23,10 //Y = 10
LOOP2:
LDI R24,10 //Z = 10
LOOP3:
 
NOP // --> 1cc

DEC R24 // Z = Z - 1
BRNE LOOP3
 
DEC R23 // Y = Y - 1
BRNE LOOP2
 
DEC R22 // X = X - 1
BRNE LOOP1
RET

DELAY2:
LDI R22,30 //X = 10
LOOP4:
LDI R23,40 //Y = 10
LOOP5:
LDI R24,50 //Z = 10
LOOP6:
 
NOP // --> 1cc

DEC R24 // Z = Z - 1
BRNE LOOP6
 
DEC R23 // Y = Y - 1
BRNE LOOP5
 
DEC R22 // X = X - 1
BRNE LOOP4
RET
```

But I still unable to create a custom character and controlling specific pixels in a 5x7 LCD Display, and I understand how to do it in C but not in assembly Language, and I am testing it using Proteus simulation not with a real life Arduino.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What display device are you using? Does the documentation describe commands for creating and displaying custom characters?

Comment: Most text LCD displays have eight programmable (RAM) characters that you use to define your custom characters.  These are character codes 0 through 7.  Check your LCD datasheet for the commands to update those.  That's all you can control in terms of character pixels.  All the rest are in your LCD's ROM.  As for creating the bitmap of each character, either manually (only 8 chars) or use a program such as: aspisys.com/editfont.exe (Win console) or editfont (Linux i386)

Comment: If you can do it in C you can do it in asm it is just another programming langauge, do it the same way.

Comment: The thing is, in I can create an array size=8 that have the value in binary of hex of which pixel is ON or OFF on the display and then write it down, but still can't recreate it in assembly language. And the thing is I need the code to be in assembly language and not in c.